# How to clear new Realm-core associated buildtime warning error message

Tags: swift, realm, warnings

I have suddenly started to receive an apparently harmless (but are any poorly understood warning messages genuinely harmless?) buildtime warning message related to realm-core:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

On close inspection the process appears be generating a reference to an invalid directory due to the mis-spelling of realm as relam.

/Users/chrislindsey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Todoey-gktnvdqnraspkjcfgabovmizmivy/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-core/src/***relam***/status_with.hpp

Why should this start to happen (what could I have done for this to occur?). Can I reset anything to stop it happening and clear the warning message?

With thanks to Jay 5 for his comment - yes this was caused by the Realm-core version becoming outdated over time and the simple expedient of pressing File\Packages\Update to latest versions in XCode solved the issue directly.

Comment: You've got an older realm-core file there. Get the 11.4.1 or higher which resolves the issue.

Comment: @Jay 5 Many thanks. Of course I should have thought of that myself and am embarrassed that I did not update versions as an automatic first step before bothering the forum with such trivia. Lesson learnt!